# How to config TIMER in TIM_BASE for stm32f746NG_Discovery in RTOS?

Tags: c

I want to use timer8 of stm32f746NG_Discovery board, but I don't know how can config it.Does anyone have a simple code in keil,please?

Comment: Keil is the IDE not the programming language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tim 8 configure update interrupt

```
__HAL_RCC_TIM8_CLK_ENABLE();

TIM8 -> PSC = 999;
TIM8 -> ARR = SystemCoreClock / ((TIM8 -> PSC + 1) * freq) - 1;
TIM8 -> EGR |= TIM_EGR_UG;
if(TIM8 -> SR & TIM_SR_UIF) TIM8 -> SR = ~(TIM_SR_UIF);
TIM8 -> DIER |= TIM_DIER_UIE;
TIM8 -> CR1 = TIM_CR1_CEN;

NVIC_EnableIRQ(TIM8_TRG_COM_TIM14_IRQn);
```

Comment: Thanks P__J__.
1. I don't understand 
"if(TIM8 -> SR & TIM_SR_UIF) TIM8 -> SR = ~(TIM_SR_UIF);"
what dose it mean?
2.Could you explain how can I use interrupt of this timer to blink a led please?